# How to Write to Active Directory using VB.NET or SQL or API?

Tags: vb.net, api, asp.net-web-api, active-directory, integration

I'm trying to read an employee's HR information from a HR application's Web API (e.g. ADP's HR application) and then use that data to update a user's attributes in Active Directory (e.g. email, street address, job title, and other basic info). I'm able to retrieve the data from the WebAPI easily and store in a SQL Server database. I'm now trying to figure out how to automate the writing to Active Directory.

Can someone point me where I can start?

I've tried looking online for some time and have not found anything that is making sense to me.

Comment: a reference about AD and VB for you https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19689/Working-with-Active-Directory-in-VB-NET

Comment: The Code Project link is a good start. I wrote a few article about programming with AD that can give you some more information: https://www.gabescode.com My code samples are in C#, but the principles can be applied to any language (especially [the article about performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html)), and they can be translated to VB.NET if you need.